# Fixed effects regression vs. pooled OLS with dummies

Tags: r, regression, fixed, effects

I have a panel data set and I am trying to run a regression. Please find the code for my models below, I also attached the results table. From my understanding, Model 2 and Model 3 should give the same results. However, I get the following results (see picture). Does anybody know what could be the issue? I also get the following error (see picture).

```
Model1 <-plm((op_margin) ~ pur_dum + log(firm_age) + log(fleet_end) + factor(year) + factor(country), data= dt.airline, index=c('code','year'), model='pooling') 

Model2 <-plm((op_margin) ~ pur_dum + log(firm_age) + log(fleet_end) + factor(year), data= dt.airline, index=c('code','year'), model='pooling') 

Model3 <- plm((op_margin) ~ pur_dum + log(firm_age)+ log(fleet_end) +  factor(year), data = dt.airline, model='within', index = c('code','year'))
```

[results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62LJQ.png)

Comment: Possible migration to [Stats Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as this does not relate directly to programming.

Comment: And [pooled vs fixed effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/280578) are different model specifications.